# developing and testing Android app using USB host mode

Tags: android, usb

I found that USB host mode is available starting with Android 3.1.

Is there any way one could use the PC/MAC or update a Galaxy I9000 so it can be used for reliable development and testing?

If I use the MAC or PC USB port in Emulation, will this be the same as using the USB plug on an Android 3.1 or higher device?

Or is there really no other way than to buy a new Android device with 3.1 or higher installed already?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the date you posted your question I'm guessing you already solved it but I'll post it anyway as it might be helpful for someone else.
When you look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html)
and scroll down the page you can see emulator limitations, among those: No support for USB connections.
So you probably need to test all USB host features on the actual devices.

Comment: yes thanks - I finally got a real device which works very well with Android's USB lib